# Error correction for short strings

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

For the past few days I' was looking for an error correction code which can correct $\sim 30\%$ errors of a short string.
What is a short string? I want to encode a $7$-$10$ bit string to an $X$ bit string ($X$ as small possible) and to be able to decode the received string with $X\cdot0.3$  random located errors.
So far the best I could find was Repetition Code.
Information Theory is not my specialty so I'm struggling with this.

Comment: You mean that you have $k=7$ to $10$ raw bits to encode in a $n$ bits block , and you want to guarantee correction of arbitrary $0.3 n $ bit errors?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks a little strong correction capability, you'll need a lot of redundancy. Looking for $(n,k,t)$ BCH codes ($n,k$ are defined above, $t$ is the amonunt of correctable errors) we find, for example $(511,10,127)$ (corrects $0.248 n$ errors)

Comment: Agree with leonbloy. Codes with minimum distance $n/2$ or higher have rates going to zero asymptotically. Of course, you only want a very small code...

Comment: With $d=3n/5$ (correcting approximately $3n/10$ errors), the number of codewords, call it $A$, is bounded from above by the [Plotkin bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound)
$$A\le 2\lfloor\frac{d}{2d-n}\rfloor=6.$$ Looks like you are out of luck. You cannot have more than six codewords - not enough to encode even $3$ bits.

Comment: So something has to give. Your channel is really lousy. Any way to soup it up a bit! Add a bit of diversity? Or can you get soft information about the reliability of bits?

Comment: Maybe I can improve my channel to 23~25%, that is helping?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let your error rate be $23\%$ and let $d=23n/50$ correcting approximately $23n/100$ errors.

The Plotkin bound (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound)
can be used for the case $d$ odd only for this $d.$ You need $2d+1>n$ to use it, i.e., $\frac{46n}{50}+1>n$ which yields $1>\frac{4n}{50}$ or $n\leq 12.$

Then using the bound
$$
A_2(n,d)\leq 2 \left\lfloor \frac{\frac{23n}{50}+1}{\frac{46n}{50}+1-n}\right\rfloor=2\left\lfloor \frac{50+23n}{50-4n}\right\rfloor
$$
for odd $n\leq 12$ gives the possible parameters (taking floors to find feasible $d$)

$$A_2(7,3)\leq 18,$$ $$A_2(8,3)\leq 26,$$ $$A_2(11,5)\leq 100,$$ $$A_2(12,5)\leq 326.$$

*All this means is that the plotkin bound does not rule out the existence of such code parameters.*

There are tables of best codes known and you might want to search for those with these parameters of $n$ and $d$.

One simple idea (since you consider $p<1/4$) is to use a first order Reed-Muller code. Such a code has dimension $k=m+1,$ message length $n=2^m$ and distance $2^{m-1}=n/2.$ For 7 bits of information, you'll have a code of length $n=64.$ The decoding is via the Fast Hadamard Transform, so is quite efficient.